# Optimal control problem with Kuhn–Tucker constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, stochastic-calculus, optimal-control, karush-kuhn-tucker

**Problem:**

The stochastic optimal control problem is to minimize the discounted value of an expected weighted average of the squared cash flow $x_t$ and the squared cash flow $y_t$ by choosing the control $i_t$, which is subject to a lower bound constraint:
\begin{align}
J_t = \inf_{i_t} \ &E_t \int_t^\infty e^{-\delta (u - t)} \left( x_u^2 + \lambda y_u^2 \right) du \\
s.t. \ &i_t \geq - \xi
\end{align}
The dynamics of the states $x_t$ and $y_t$ are determined jointly by a system of forward-backward stochastic differential equations:
\begin{align}
dx_t &= \left[ i_t - y_t +b \right] dt + \sigma^x dZ_t \\
\label{eq_a178}
dy_t &= \left[ \delta y_t - c x_t \right] dt + \sigma^y dZ_t
\end{align}

**My approach:**

The Hamiltonian is given by:
\begin{align}
H_t = x_t^2 + b_t^2 + E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_t}{dt} \right] - \mu_i (i_t + \xi)
\end{align}
where:
\begin{align}
E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_t}{dt} \right] &= J_{x_t} E_t \left[ \frac{dx_t}{dt} \right] + \frac{1}{2} J_{x_t x_t} E_t \left[ \frac{(dx_t)^2}{dt} \right] + J_{y_t} E_t \left[ \frac{dy_t}{dt} \right] + \frac{1}{2} J_{y_t y_t} E_t \left[ \frac{(dy_t)^2}{dt} \right] + J_{x_t y_t} E_t \left[ \frac{dx_t dy_t}{dt} \right] \nonumber \\
&= J_{x_t} \left[ i_t - y_t + b \right] + \frac{1}{2} J_{x_t x_t} (\sigma^x)^2 + J_{y_t} \left[ \delta y_t - c x_t \right] + \frac{1}{2} J_{y_t y_t} (\sigma_t^y)^2 + J_{x_t y_t} \rho_t^{x y} \sigma^x \sigma_t^y \nonumber
\end{align}
Next, I find the optimality conditions:
\begin{align}
0 &= H_{i_t} \\
J_{x_t} &= \mu_i \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
0 &= H_{x_t} + E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_{x_t}}{dt} \right] - \delta J_{x_t} \\
0 &= 2 x_t - J_{y_t} c + E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_{x_t}}{dt} \right] - \delta J_{x_t} \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
0 &= H_{y_t} + E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_{y_t}}{dt} \right] - \delta J_{y_t} \\
0 &= 2 \lambda y_t - J_{x_t} + \delta J_{y_t} + E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_{y_t}}{dt} \right] - \delta J_{y_t} \nonumber \\
0 &= 2 \lambda y_t - J_{x_t} + E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_{y_t}}{dt} \right] \nonumber 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
0 &= \mu_i (i_t + \xi) \\
0 &= J_{x_t} (i_t + \xi) \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{align}
0 \leq \mu_i \\
0 \leq J_{x_t} \nonumber
\end{align}

**Question:**

Can you write the Hamiltonian (including the the Karush–Kuhn–Tucker component) and the conditions from the stochastic minimum principle so I can verify whether my approach is correct?

In particular, I have the following doubt: is my Hamiltonian correct, or should it be:
\begin{align}
H_t = - x_t^2 - b_t^2 + E_t \left[ \frac{dJ_t}{dt} \right] + \mu_i (i_t + \xi)
\end{align}
This in turn would flip the sign of $J_{x_t}$.